# cannot connect to x server error

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I have a camera application which I am trying to run under sudo:
but I am receiving this error

```
cannot connect to x server
```

the issue is when I dont use sudo, the program opens fine. However, there are certain parts of this application which still need admin privileges.

Since it is a GUI application, I tried to use gksudo then it opens a window asking about the password, but after entering the password the application returns and GUI does not open!

I have tried also

```
sudo xhost local:root
```

and got:

```
xhost: unable to open display""
```

I am using lubuntu 14.04

Comment: What application?

Comment: @Fabby, It is the camera manager application from IDS imaging company. It uses QT4 to build a gui application to perform Ethernet configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a cannon to kill a rabbit, but if all you're interested in `sudo`ing X applications that is what you'll need.

**The solution:**

Add to your `~/.bashrc`

```
# Fabby: 2014-11-14: http://askubuntu.com/questions/571116/
# to allow forwarding of xauth keys between users when calling su
# needs to be the last line
export $(dbus-launch)
```

**The explanation:**

- Do you know what the X server is?  OK!
- Do you know that it has a client/server technology?  OK!
- Do you know what D-Bus is? OK!
- Well, now the dbus-launch variable gets exported so that x messages from one user session can use other user's session!  Plain and simple!

Answer (score 1):

I am using SecureCRT as ssh tool, however it cannot display some plots on local host with Windows OS. I have the same problem when using Canopy.

Solutions:

1. Install Xmanager, running Xmanager Passive.
2. Add "export DISPLAY=your ip:0.0" in ~/.bashrc, source ~/.bashrc (ip is your host IP, where you wanna display plots or things like that. If you are using Windows, cmd-ipconfig, find your IP).
3. Test (i.e. $xclock, you can see a clock in your windows screen)
   or directly test your own GUI applications.

Done!